# LEFT JOIN on column where value IS NOT NULL, otherwise join on another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

- Joining 2 tables (orders, addresses)
- Orders contains columns delivery_address_id (contains NULL values) and invoice_address_id (does NOT contain NULL values)
- Addresses contains id column (does NOT contain NULL values)

Primarily, the LEFT JOIN must be performed on orders.delivery_address_id. However, in the case when its value is NULL in the row, perform LEFT JOIN on orders.invoice_address_id.

How do I deal with this?

I tried the operator `OR` but the result was not correct. I was also thinking about a CASE WHEN statement. My expectations are to get the LEFT JOIN working.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the operator `OR` in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT ....
FROM Orders o LEFT JOIN Addresses a
ON a.id = o.delivery_address_id 
OR (o.delivery_address_id IS NULL AND a.id = o.invoice_address_id);
```

Or, use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT ....
FROM Orders o LEFT JOIN Addresses a
ON a.id = COALESCE(o.delivery_address_id, o.invoice_address_id);
```

Comment: Yes, your first answer works just fine. Thank you @forpas! I will also try the second one.

Answer (score 3):

So, you want to join on `delivery_address_id`, but sometimes it's `NULL`, so you need `invoice_address_id` to be a fallback.

These situations are where the [COALESCE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-coalesce/) function really shines. `COALESCE(delivery_address_id, invoice_address_id)` will resolve to the delivery address ID if it isn't `NULL`, otherwise it will resolve to the invoice address ID instead.

Thus we can achieve the join you want:

```sql
    SELECT
        orders.some_field,
        addresses.address
      FROM
        orders
 LEFT JOIN
        addresses
        ON
        COALESCE(orders.delivery_address_id, orders.invoice_address_id) = addresses.id
```

Comment: Thank you for recommendations. Both solutions work, but I think I will stick with COALESCE as @forpas also suggested.